# Javascript Jquery Fadeout Woes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My javascript isn't currently working. I guess while I'm at it, is there any programs that I can use that can essentially give me errors made so that I am able to trouble shoot myself?

Javascript...

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-ui.min.js">
       $(document).ready(function() {
          $(".button").click(function(){
             $("#ticketTable").fadeOut( 'slow', function(){ 
              });
          });
       });
    </script>
```

Button used to fadeout...

```
<button class="button">Respond</button>
```

HTML That I want to fade out...

```
<div id="ticketTable">
<table border="1" width="1000" class="transparent">
            <tr><th width="15%">Ticket</th><th width="15%">Queue</th><th width="15%">Severity</th><th width="15%">Created</th><th width="15%">Creator</th><th width="25%">Subject</th></tr>
        </table></div>
```

Comment: do you get any console errors? - seems to be working here: http://jsfiddle.net/LypLcyew/

Comment: As per your second question on how to troubleshoot it yourself, if you are using Chrome or Firefox, you can press [F12] and it will show you a 'developer' console - you can look at the console there for any JS errors

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine but the way you are including your .JS file (and later initializing behaviour) seems incorrect.

Try adding this to your page's `<head>` tag, and change your JS `<script>` tag like this:

```
 <head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
     <!--other script and also external css included over here-->

     <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function() {
          $(".button").click(function(){
             $("#ticketTable").fadeOut( 'slow', function(){ 
              });
          });
       });
    </script>
</head>
```

**[DEMO: JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LypLcyew/)**